# How do I fix my code for plotting a histogram?

Tags: r

I am sorry if this is basic, I am new to R and starting from scratch here.

I would like to plot a histogram of the following data ( each sample has a Shannon diversity metric representing the richness and abundance of species in each sample).

Here is my data, currently a data frame (called `shannon_divplot`) with one column called `shannon_diversity` and 6 observations.

```
                shannon_diversity
      Control1  3.309361
      Control2  3.664494
      Control3  3.269842
      Disease1  2.572888
      Disease2  1.530877
      Disease3  2.357401
```

I would like to plot a histogram that shows the Shannon diversity value for each sample. I then wish to compute an one way ANOVA followed by a post-hoc Tukey test. Here is the code which I have used, strangely the `hist()` function is just creating a data frame not an actual graph.

```
 hist(shannon_divplot$shannondiversity, 
  main="Shannon Diversity",
  xlab="Samples", breaks=15)
```

Will I need to convert my data frame to this

```
         Samples     shannon_div
   1    Control1    3.309361
   2    Control2    3.664494
   3    Control3    3.269842
   4    Disease1    2.572888
   5    Disease2    1.530877
   6    Disease3    2.357401
```

And use code such as

```
   plot(shannon_div ~Samples, 
    data=shannon_divplot, 
    main="Shannon Diversity", xlab="Sample" )
```

?

When calculating the ANOVA I am also going wrong as p values are not computed. It just gives me this;

```
                Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
   Samples      5  3.084  0.6168

   aov.shannon = aov(shannon_div ~Samples, data=shannon_divplot)
   summary(aov.shannon)

   TukeyHSD(aov.shannon)
```

Apologies again if this is too basic, any help would be appreciated.

Edit: If I wanted to compare collectively control vs disease, so there would be more than one value for each group, how would I need to arrange my data frame or code in order to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is more usually called a **bar plot**: "histogram" is usually reserved for a plot that shows the frequency distribution of a *continuous* variable. `barplot()` will do what you want, you don't need to change the data format:

```
## input data
dd <- read.table(header=TRUE,text="
     shannon_diversity
      Control1  3.309361
      Control2  3.664494
      Control3  3.269842
      Disease1  2.572888
      Disease2  1.530877
      Disease3  2.357401
")

barplot(dd$shannon_diversity,names.arg=rownames(dd),
        ylab="Shannon diversity")
```

Your other question is harder (and it's a statistical question, not a programming question). You can't do an ANOVA across groups unless you have replication within the groups.  Since you only have one data point per treatment, ANOVA doesn't produce a p-value.

If you want to compare control vs disease (3 observations each):

```
dd$grp <- sub("[1-3]","",rownames(dd))
anova(lm(shannon_diversity ~ grp, data=dd))
```

(There's no point doing a Tukey post-hoc on an ANOVA with two groups [and in my opinion Tukey post-hoc tests are overused anyway ...])